# TFS IIS www-authenticate: Basic header

Tags: tfs, iis-8, redgate, www-authenticate

I'm using a TFS 2017.3 version on my Windows 2012 server IIS 8.

When I'm trying an HTTP request to my TFS server (Using Source Control for Oracle which is a [Red-Gate](https://www.red-gate.com) tool for Oracle DB source control) with a 3rd Party tool that uses libgit2sharp.

Using wireshark, I found out that I'm getting 3 `www-authenticate` headers (within this order):

1. `www-authenticate: Bearer`
2. `www-authenticate: Basic <realm>`
3. `www-authenticate: NTLM`

I'm only allowing Windows Authentication on my IIS (With NTLM provider).

This is quite problematic for me because I need the order to be different. I want to use Windows Authentication but when the `www-authenticate: Basic` comes before `www-authenticate: NTLM` the NTLM authentication isn't successful (Like in [this case](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues/4039)).

It's quite weird because I've disabled Basic Authentication on IIS and still the `www-authenticate: Basic` is present in the HTTP response HEADERS.

When the Basic Authentication is enabled with Windows Authentication (NTLM provider) then suddenly `www-authenticate: NTLM` comes before `www-authenticate: Basic` header (Which is super weird because when Basic Authentication was disabled then it didn't behave in the same way).

Any suggestions and tips what should I do and how can I manage the `www-authenticate` headers order on IIS or in TFS?

Maybe someone knows how can I remove the `www-authenticate: Basic` header when Basic Authentication is disabled?

Is it IIS problem or something TFS doing regardless of IIS?

Comment: Just try to remove the `Basic Authentication` feature from Windows 2012 server, then check what behavior it appears.

Comment: I have tried to remove it and still nothing changes @AndyLi-MSFT

Comment: Seems it's an issue with the LibGit2Sharp based on the discussion in [this thread](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues/4039#issuecomment-269631357), Have you tried the latest LibGit2Sharp ?

Comment: I did try, unfortunately the 3rd party tool I’m using isn’t able to work with different version. Although, in the thread, other people using tfs and the latest version of LibGit2Sharp not solving the issue with the www-authenticate headers as I mentioned.

Comment: It isn't fixed yet.

Comment: I mean the LibGit2Sharp issue is not fixed yet :)